Can two different measures have the same first order stochastic dominance?
$(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ is the common probability  triple, where $S=[0,1]$, $\Sigma$ is the Borel sigma algebra, and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.
$X:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is a r.v.
There are two different measures, $\mu,\nu$, on $S=[0,1]$.
First order stochastic dominance FOSD is defined here.
For all $X,Y$ we have: $X$ $\mu$-FOSD $Y$ $\iff$ $X$ $\nu$-FOSD $Y$.
Can the two measure be different (excluding those trivial cases such as two measures are the same a.s.)?

First, your notation is unclear. The interval $[0,1]$ seems to play no role for the question.  If you fixes the notation (write it out with more standard probability notation) you should see fast that the answer must be NO, if you mean for any r.v. $X, Y$. Then there might exist some such pair ...

@kjetilbhalvorsen Ok let me try to be more standard.

Your question is ambiguous because it lacks needed qualifiers: in the references to "$X$" and $Y$" after "given," is $X$ the RV stipulated previously?  If not, do you assume there exists an $X$ or for all $X$ the following equivalence holds?  Likewise, what are the qualifiers for $Y$?

It is for all $X,Y$. I found the solution and I will post it here

Assume that $\mu, \nu$ satisfy $X \: \mu\text{-FOSD} \: Y \Longleftrightarrow X \: \nu\text{-FOSD} \: Y$ for all X, Y.

For $A, B \subset S$, such that $\mu(A) < \mu(B)$ denote
$$X := 2\chi_{\bar A}, \: Y := \chi_{\bar B}.$$
We have $X \: \mu\text{-FOSD} \: Y $ and therefore $X \: \nu\text{-FOSD} \: Y $ by the assumption. It gives us
$$ \nu(A) < \nu(B). \label{r} $$
Analogously, taking $A, B \subset S$, such that $\mu(A) \le \mu(B)$ we achieve
$$ \nu(A) \le \nu(B).  $$
The 2 in $X$ was used here.

The same inequalities are true if we go from $\nu$ to $\mu$.
Combining it all together we get that
$$ \mu(A) = \mu(B) \Longleftrightarrow \nu(A) = \nu(B). $$
In the end we use the fact, that Lebesque measure is the only measure that is preserved under translations.
For the last step, we want to add a detailed proof. We want to show that, in general, if
$$P(E) = P(E') \iff Q(E) = Q(E')$$
Then, $P,Q$ are of "similar" shape.
Let $p=P(E)$, then $P(E)=P([0,p))$ so $Q(E)=Q([0,p))=f(p)$
Which tells us $Q$ is just some increasing function applied to $P$.
$P([0,x))=P([x,2x))$ so $Q([x,2x))=Q([0,x))=f(x)$ which gives us
$$f(2x)=Q([0,2x))=Q([0,x))+Q([x,2x))=2f(x)$$
By doing the same thing for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we get $f(nx)=nf(x)$.
From this it follows that for any $n \in \mathbb{Q}$ we get $f(nx)=nf(x)$, and because $f$ is increasing we get $f(nx)=nf(x)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{R}$, telling us that $f(x)=rx$, so $Q$ is just a scaling factor, $r$, applied to $P$.
Hence
$$\mathbb{E}_Q[X]=r\mathbb{E}_P[X]$$
